# Decimated xticks in hour-format in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, axis

I'm working with Python 3.6 and matplotlib to draw a plot of a list with **24 elements**.

I'd like to have only **6 ticks** on x-axis, one every 4 elements; also, I'd like that these 6 ticks would be equally spaced and in hour-format, like:

```
00:00, 01:00, 02:00, 03:00, 04:00, 05:00
```

Which is a good way to do this?

Comment: [MultipleLocator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-ticker-multiplelocator-class-in-python/)?

Comment: Thanks for your interest @QuangHoang! Could you expand your answer a little bit with a sample code? By using MultipleLocator(4), for example, the first tick (after the 0-tick) is equal to '4', while I'd like to have '1'. I'd like to have one tick every 4 values, where ticks values are numbered progressively (like: 1, 2, 3, ecc), and the first tick (after the 0-tick) is '1'.

Answer (score 1):

For matplotlib there's always multiple ways to do the same thing. You can use the method `plt.xticks(<ticks>,<labels>)` where `<ticks>` is a list of integers of where you want the tick to appear and `<labels>` is a list of labels. If you have multiple plots in one figure and want to set each axis independently you can use `ax.set_xticks(<ticks>)` and `ax.set_xticklabels(<labels>)` but it requires you to assign your axes object to some variable name, for example by using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` .

See below for example. If you are curious why the last index is 23 and not 24 I can explain further.

```
# === Method using plt.plot() directly ==== 
# --- generate data -----
data=[]
for i in list(range(24)):
    data += [random()]

# --- plot data ----    
    
plt.xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20,23], ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00","05:00","6:00"]) # note that the final index is 23 not 24
plt.plot(data) # plt.plot() can be called either before or after plt.xticks() in this case

plt.show()

# === Method using plt.subplots() ====
# --- generate random data again to show its not the same plot -----
data=[]
for i in list(range(24)):
    data += [random()]

# --- plot data ----

fig,ax= plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
plt.xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20,23], ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00","05:00","6:00"]) #in this case .xticks cannot be called before .subplots()
#use the below two lines and remove the line above if you have multiple subplots and want to set each subplot to have a different x-axis
#ax.set_xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20,23])
#ax.set_xticklabels(["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00","05:00","6:00"])

ax.plot(data)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @FlummoxedCivet, very useful! I guess that the reason why the last index is '23', instead of '24', concerns the fact that Python indexing is '0-based', isn't it?

Comment: You use 6 groups of 4 elements indeed, and each time the tick lands on the first of each group. So for the first group it's 0, then you add 4 and get 4, etc. and you get 8,12,...20, 24. But if it ended on 24 it would imply the existence of a 7th group and you only have 6. So instead it falls on the last of the final group, 23.

Comment: Ok but, doing so, the distance between the last two ticks is lesser than that between other ticks; so, your solution doesn't completely solve my problem.